# How to generate key value pair objects from an array in typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have an array of ids and wanted to make an array object with adding a key "id" on it in typescript

```
array = ['6016b86edeccb2444cc78eef','6016b86edeccb2444cc78eee']

result = [{"id":"6016b86edeccb2444cc78eef"},{"id":"6016b878deccb2444cc78ef0"}]
```

Comment: `array.map(id => ({id}))`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) as follows:

```js
const array = ['6016b86edeccb2444cc78eef','6016b86edeccb2444cc78eee'];

const result = array.map(id => ({id}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This one is working, thanks for quick help @Majed Badawi